# xgboost inference in C

Tags: python, c

I implemented the xgboost for inference in C:

```
int main() {
    const char* modelPath = "model.json";
    BoosterHandle booster;
    XGBoosterCreate(NULL, 0, &booster);
    int b = XGBoosterLoadModel(booster, modelPath);
    printf("%d", b);
    const char* test_path = "x_test.libsvm?format=libsvm";
    DMatrixHandle test;
    XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(test_path, 0, &test);
    bst_ulong out_len;
    const float* out_result;
    int a = XGBoosterPredictFromDMatrix(booster, test, 0, 0, 
                                           &out_len, &out_result);
    printf("%d", a);
    XGDMatrixFree(test);
    XGBoosterFree(booster);
}
```

XGBoosterLoadModel returns 0 (ok) but XGBoosterPredictFromDMatrix returns -1 that means error. Does anyone have an idea of what I am wrong?

I tried also to load the trained model with the bin in python format but it does not work.